# S3 How to route all the requests to the same resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Im thinking of hosting a website on S3. The content of the webpages will be stored elsewhere on our web service. Therefore S3 would only be delivering a HTML page, CSS and crucially JS. Then AJAX requests would retrieve data and display it on the webpage.

Examples of what im looking for

```
https://www.example.com/something/another/thing
routes to s3/mybucket/index.html

https://www.example.com/something
routes to s3/mybucket/index.html

https://example.com
routes to s3/mybucket/index.html
```

Therefore the question is, how can I route all the requests to the same resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to figure it out. Using ReplaceKeyPrefixWith does not actually redirect the page it just routes it to the desired destination. Using KeyPrefixEquals set to "/" means all requests will be re-routed, except the index.html.

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>/</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>index.html</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I have much experience doing this, but it is an interesting idea for building a single page web application. Take a look at [this](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/10/04/web-page-redirects-on-amazon-s3-hosted-websites/) for redirects. Also, consider using [Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) to serve your CSS.

Comment: Im not looking for redirects as they change the URL, I want it to serve the same content from different request paths.